# Clicking hyperlink in angular js changing url instead of toggling effect in same view

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

While using anchor tag in View1.html when I click the link, instead of getting the toggling effect, the view is becoming blank as the url is changing to "#" on clicking the hyperlink. I want to remain on the same view and just do the toggling effect on the same view. 
How to remain on the same view after clicking the anchor tag and have toggling?
 
This is index.html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/shared/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/shared/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

    myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: "partials/View1.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }

    );
```

This is View1.html:

```
<a href="#"  id="abc">Slide Toggle</a><br>
<div class="toggle4" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:200px;"></div>
<p class="toggle4">I'm visible on load!</p>
<script>
$('#abc').click(function() {

    $('.toggle4').slideToggle('fast');

    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's possible that the `#abc` element doesn't exist when the javascript fires due to angular. Try delegating the event to the body with jQuery. `$('body').on('click','#abc', function(){$().slideToggle('fast');return false;});`
This will allow the event to be bound to an element that 100% exists when the script runs, then that element can test to see if a click event was fired from `#abc`.

Comment: instead of `href="#"` try with `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: @ShamSUP, it is not working

Comment: @ Guruprasad Rao, it did not work either

Comment: In my comment I accidentally had a typo, and put only `$()` instead of `$('.toggle4').slideToggle('fast')` so try fixing that if you haven't. If that doesn't work, try using my method, but putting the script in index.html rather than the template file. It appears to be a binding issue, most likely because the element doesn't exist when that script runs to bind the event.